# Erro ao buscar cabeçalhos HTTP em Web Services php

Tags: php, web-service, soap

Estou aprendendo a criar Web Services e estou fazendo dois arquivos em php, server e cliente.
Server.php

```
<?php
class functions
{

    function mensagem()
    {
        return 'hello server';
    }
    function soma($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }

}

$options = array('uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1/teste/index.php');
$server  = new soapServer(null, $options);

$server->setClass('functions');
$server->handle();


?>
```

Cliente.php

```
<?php

$options = array('location' => 'http://127.0.0.1/teste/cliente.php', 
'uri' => '127.0.0.1/teste/index.php');
$cliente = new soapClient(null, $options);

try{

    print($cliente->soma(2, 3));

} catch(Exception $e)
{

    print $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

Ao executar o script cliente.php da o seguinte erro

```
Error fetching HTTP headers
```

Já aumentei até o timeout para 600s, da forma como vi no StackOverFlow ingles, mas só deixou mas demorada a mesma resposta. Alguem Pode dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Você tentou aumentar o **tempo de resposta**? Não deveria ser o **timeout**?

Comment: sim sim. escrevi errado.